# Duda Flujos de entrada de C

Tags: c, struct, scanf

El siguiente programa me funciona correctamente en C++ con sus respectivos cambios (cin y cout) sin embargo a la hora de pasarlo a C la entrada proporcionada por teclado falla.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


struct etapa{
    int h, m, s;
}etapas[3], *puntero_etapa = etapas;


void giveData(){

  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    printf("Introduzca el numero de horas: \n" );
    scanf("%i\n", &puntero_etapa[i].h);
    //cin>>puntero_etapa[i].h;          
    printf("Introduzca el numero de minutos: \n" );
    scanf("%i\n", &((puntero_etapa + i)-> m));
    //cin>>(puntero_etapa + i)-> m;
    printf("Introduzca el numero de segundos: \n" );
    scanf("%i\n", (&(puntero_etapa + i)-> s));
    //cin>>(puntero_etapa + i)-> s;
  }
}

void timeEtapas(const struct etapa *puntero_etapa1){
  int time = 0, time1 = 0, time2 = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    time += (puntero_etapa1 + i)-> h;
    time1 += (puntero_etapa1 + i)-> m;
    time2 += (puntero_etapa1 + i)-> s;
    printf("La duracion total es: Horas: %i minutos: %i segundos:  
            %i\n",time, time1, time2 );
  }
}


int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  giveData();
  timeEtapas(puntero_etapa);
  return 0;
}
```

Provocando una salida de este tipo:

```
Introduzca el numero de horas: 
888
0
Introduzca el numero de minutos: 
8
Introduzca el numero de segundos: 
8
Introduzca el numero de horas: 
8
Introduzca el numero de minutos: 
8
Introduzca el numero de segundos: 
8
Introduzca el numero de horas: 
8
Introduzca el numero de minutos: 
8
Introduzca el numero de segundos: 
8
```

Como veis solo falla en la primera iteración, la cual me la pide dos veces y por lo tanto se va acarreando hacia abajo.¿Como solucionarlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El salto de línea en la lectura te sobra:

```
scanf("%i\n", &puntero_etapa[i].h);
//       ^^
```

Debes dejarlo así:

```
scanf("%i", &puntero_etapa[i].h);
```

Y lo mismo para el resto de lecturas

Comment: Muchas gracias, acabo de corregirlo y ya me funciona adecuadamente.